# Old Powerpoint file will not open in Office 07

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How can i open .ppt files from Powerpoint MS Office 97-2003 in Office 07? Have tried several ideas from various sources but none work! Desperately need to open an old ppt file to meet a deadline in 6 hours- any suggestions will be highly appreciated- Omar

Comment: What (exactly) have you tried, and what happened?  (And what operating system are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to open it with [LibreOffice Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/download).

Another way is to import it to [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/)  or [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/).